# Return value from anonymous subfunction

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I call a function and expect a value to be returned.

> var spriteImageLoaded = tryLoadSpriteImage(data,hrefObj);

```
tryLoadSpriteImage = function(data,hrefObj){
      $(data).each(function(){
              if ($(this)[0].nodeName == "STYLE")
              {
                  var styleTxt = $(this)[0].innerHTML
                  //console.log(styleTxt);
                  var urlImage = styleTxt.match(/\((.*)\)/g)[0].replace('(','').replace(')','');
                  //console.log("url image loaded:"+urlImage);
                  hrefDivInsertImageUrl(hrefObj, urlImage);
                  saveImage(hrefObj.href, urlImage);
                  return hrefObj.div;
              }
          });
}
```

I expected   `var spriteImageLoaded` = `hrefObj.div`. But instead it is `undefined`.
How to return value correctly?

Comment: Can you provide some jsfiddle with example HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call to `return` within the callback function of jQuery `each` is equivalent to a break in a standard for loop. So what you're actually doing, is iterate through each entry of `data`, and breaking after the first that has a node name "STYLE", and not returning anything from your function's point of view.

If you want to return `hrefObj.div` you should use:

```
tryLoadSpriteImage = function(data,hrefObj){
    $(data).each(function(){
        if ($(this)[0].nodeName == "STYLE")
        {
            var styleTxt = $(this)[0].innerHTML
            //console.log(styleTxt);
            var urlImage = styleTxt.match(/\((.*)\)/g)[0].replace('(','').replace(')','');
            //console.log("url image loaded:"+urlImage);
            hrefDivInsertImageUrl(hrefObj, urlImage);
            saveImage(hrefObj.href, urlImage);
            return; //exits the each loop
        }
    });
    return hrefObj.div; //returns the div
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
tryLoadSpriteImage = function(data,hrefObj){
      return $(data).each(function(){
              if ($(this)[0].nodeName == "STYLE")
              {
                  var styleTxt = $(this)[0].innerHTML
                  //console.log(styleTxt);
                  var urlImage = styleTxt.match(/\((.*)\)/g)[0].replace('(','').replace(')','');
                  //console.log("url image loaded:"+urlImage);
                  hrefDivInsertImageUrl(hrefObj, urlImage);
                  saveImage(hrefObj.href, urlImage);
                  return hrefObj.div;
              }
          });
}
```